# What is the replacement for AssoGiate?

Tags: icons, mime-type, file-type

During the update to Saucy, the AssoGiate module is removed as it has been declared obsolete.
I can find no replacement for the editor of the MIME file types database which is compatible with UBUNTU 13.10.
Can anyone point me towards the replacement module?

Comment: Mabeye try updating your ubuntu version to 21.10 (If it is supported); that version is very old.